# Error building .click package with click build .: '...' is not a directory

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages, golang

Error I get when building a .click package, which is an Ubuntu Phone scope:

> ERROR: 'my-scope' is not a directory

Any idea what this could be referring to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Turned out that "scope"'s corresponding value is supposed to specify a directory:

`"hooks": {
        "my-scope": {
            "apparmor": "my-scope.apparmor",
            "scope": "my-scope"
        }
    },`

I changed `"scope": "my-scope"` to `"scope": "."` to specify the current directory:

`"hooks": {
        "my-scope": {
            "apparmor": "my-scope.apparmor",
            "scope": "."
        }
    },`

My .click package now builds and installs!